# How to get TypeCode of an Array of byte?

Tags: c#

I need to tell the type of an unknown variable. `Type.GetTypeCode()` seems good enough for my purposes, but in the case of `byte[]` it does not provided the desired result.

Here is the simplified code for my problem:

```
var bytes = new byte[10];
var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(bytes.GetType());

// Actual result: typeCode equals Object
// Desired result (pseudocode): "array of TypeCode.Byte"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TypeCode` is an enumeration, and given there is no enum member representing "array of Byte", you'll get `TypeCode.Object`, [because](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **Object**
>   A general type representing any reference or value type not explicitly represented by another TypeCode.

You're probably looking for [`Type.GetElementType()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.110).aspx), as that returns:

> The Type of the object encompassed or referred to by the current array [...]

Using that returned Type you then in turn can call `Type.GetTypeCode()`:

```
var byteArray = new byte[0];

Type arrayType = byteArray.GetType();
Type elementType =  arrayType.GetElementType();
TypeCode elementTypeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(elementType);
```

Here, `elementTypeCode` will be `TypeCode.Byte`.

Answer (score 4):

```
var typeCodeName = bytes.GetType().Name;//Byte[]
var typeCodeFName = bytes.GetType().FullName;//System.Byte[]
```

You can return Byte[] if you are taking the Name of GetType. If this is what you desire.